# Merely copying in this or that dictionary definition 'does not an answer make'

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

In one of my answers, I had only copy-pasted definitions from a dictionary so the moderator commented on my post and said:

> *Merely copying in this or that dictionary definition **does not an answer make***.

What kind of grammatical structure is this? Does it have a name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd call it ***stylistic*** (or ***poetic / literary***) ***inversion***. Familiar to many in contexts like [***One swallow does not a summer make***,](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swallow_does_not_a_summer_make) it may have been more common in natural speech a few centuries ago (I've no idea), but it's definitely "non-standard" today.

DON'T COPY THIS STYLE - unless you're *really* good at English, and wish to be "whimsical"!

---

BUT... note that the specific verb combination ***do + make*** in this negating / refuting construction ***X does/do not Y make*** is something of a [SNOWCLONE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone) (another familiar variant is [Stone walls do not a prison make](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/stone-walls-do-not-a-prison-make-verb-object-inversion.202783/)). It's been more closely examined by [***Why is “xxxx doth not a yyyy make” considered valid English***?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27420/why-is-xxxx-doth-not-a-yyyy-make-considered-valid-english) as asked on English Language & Usage, if you're interested.

---

EDIT: Having just actually looked at the linked ELU question myself, I think it's worth flagging up what the top answer there says:

> *this little short phrase has a lot going on. Three figures of speech, **idiom, [hyperbaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbaton)** and **ellipsis**, and an archaic verb particle.*

From which it should be obvious that technically speaking the "answer" here is *"**hyperbaton** and **ellipsis**"* (though I don't see how knowing the first of those two words helps anyone learn English, since I never needed to know it myself until now).

Note that the "archaic verb particle" referred to above is the word ***doth*** - often used instead of ***do*** in this construction, primarily as a hint to the audience that the speaker is being "facetiously archaic".

Comment: Now be honest. Do you *really* care about knowing the specific word **hyperbation**? Personally, I have no doubt I'll forget it myself very soon, having never needed to know the word until now! :)

Comment: I read the question you linked and I've never heard 'hyperbaton' before. I saw that sentence structure yesterday and it sounded pleasant to my ears :P And as always, I'll forget it in no time. :D

Comment: It was [used by tchrist](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/534920/formal-or-polite-alternative-for-fing-around/534926#comment1308770_534926) (he often uses old structures like this in chatroom).

Comment: Try to remember the bit about including ***doth***. If you ever come out with this construction yourself, using ***doth*** instead of ***do*** guarantees that people will understand you're being flippant (they won't just think you don't know English syntax very well! :)

Comment: ‘Doth’ is an archaic form of *‘does’* (third person singular), not ‘do’.  And it was generally used only as an auxiliary; the main verb was *‘doest’*.  (If you're going to use an archaic form, at least use it properly!  “I do, thou doest, he doeth, we do, you do, they do.”  But “I do sleep, thou dost sleep, he doth sleep, we do sleep, you do sleep, they do sleep.”)

Comment: @gidds: Methinks the gentleman doth protest too much! :) Actually, I'm impressed with how consistently people get it right. Hundreds of written instances of [*Stone walls **do** not a prison make*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22walls+do+not+a+prison+make%22), but not a single one with ***doth*** in that exact sequence. Although I did find [*Iron bars **doth** not a prison make, but iron-clad ideas do*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bars+doth+not+a+prison+make%22), and a quick glance at the context soon convinced me the writer knew *exactly* what he was doing there!

Answer (score 2):

To pull out and emphasize one piece of the current top-voted (and only) answer...

The specific stock phrase *"X does not a Y make"* entered the culture via Richard Lovelace's 1642 poem ["To Althea, From Prison"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44657/to-althea-from-prison):

> Stone walls do not a prison make,
>   Nor iron bars a cage;
>   Minds innocent and quiet take
>   That for an hermitage.

The phrase's literal meaning is the same as "X does not make a Y," but the inverted phrasing is specifically an allusion to Lovelace's poem.

The literary allusion is unimportant in most contexts, including in the context you quoted; just a bit of cleverness that some readers will get and some won't. It's no different from if someone said "I hold this StackOverflow answer to be self-evident" or "Friends, Romans, countrymen, this is a good answer" or "Answer, or answer not; there is no 'comment'."